# JavaScript Cosine similarity function

Tags: javascript, similarity, trigonometry

I am trying to create a cosine similarity function and then display the results in a HTML element. I have written the following:

```js
function cosinesim(A,B){
        var dotproduct=0;
        var mA=0;
        var mB=0;
        for(i = 0; i < A.length;){
            dotproduct += (A[i] * B[i]);
            mA += (A[i]*A[i]);
            mB += (B[i]*B[i]);
        }
        mA = Math.sqrt(mA);
        mB = Math.sqrt(mB);
        var similarity = (dotproduct)/(mA)*(mB)
        return similarity;
    }

//.....

var array1 = [1,0,0,1];
var array2 = [1,0,0,0];

var p = cosinesim(array1,array2);
document.getElementById("sim").innerHTML = String(p);
```

I have tested and both the arrays I am inputting are the same length, however when my code runs to this bit it crashes and I cant seem to find what is wrong.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please add a definition of array1 and array2 in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed `i++` in your loop which leads to an endless one

replacing `for(i = 0; i < A.length;)` to `for(i = 0; i < A.length;i++)` fixed the issue

Comment: Serious mistake also here: (dotproduct)/(mA)*(mB) is wrong because of operator precedence.. Use (dotproduct)/(mA * mB) instead, otherwise the score will not be in [0,1]

Answer (score 11):

```
function cosinesim(A, B) {
    var dotproduct = 0;
    var mA = 0;
    var mB = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        dotproduct += A[i] * B[i];
        mA += A[i] * A[i];
        mB += B[i] * B[i];
    }

    mA = Math.sqrt(mA);
    mB = Math.sqrt(mB);
    var similarity = dotproduct / (mA * mB);

    return similarity;
}


var array1 = [1, 0, 0, 1];
var array2 = [1, 0, 0, 0];

var p = cosinesim(array1, array2);

console.log(p);
```

This should give the actual cosine similarity.
You were missing:

1. The `var i` and `i++` in your `for` loop, as mentioned before.
2. Extra brackets around `(mA * mB)` in this line: `var similarity = dotproduct / (mA * mB);` Without them, the division is done before the multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

Using the map and reduce the functionality of javascript

```js
function dotp(x, y) {
  function dotp_sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  function dotp_times(a, i) {
    return x[i] * y[i];
  }
  return x.map(dotp_times).reduce(dotp_sum, 0);
}

function cosineSimilarity(A,B){
  var similarity = dotp(A, B) / (Math.sqrt(dotp(A,A)) * Math.sqrt(dotp(B,B)));
  return similarity;
}


var array1 = [1,2,2,1];
var array2 = [1,3,2,0];

var p = cosineSimilarity(array1,array2);

console.log(p);
```

Hope this helps!! Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function cosinesim(A,B){
        var dotproduct=0;
        var mA=0;
        var mB=0;
        for(i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            dotproduct += (A[i] * B[i]);
            mA += (A[i]*A[i]);
            mB += (B[i]*B[i]);
        }
        mA = Math.sqrt(mA);
        mB = Math.sqrt(mB);
        var similarity = (dotproduct)/(mA)*(mB)
        return similarity;
    }


var array1 = [1,0,0,1];
var array2 = [1,0,0,0];

var p = cosinesim(array1,array2);

console.log(p);
```

Comment: It can go above `1` while it should be between `-1` an `1` I think. It gives e.g. `2` if I compare `[1,1,0,0]` and `[1,1,0,0]`.

Comment: @gazdagergo n@HardikShah There are problems with floats and math in JS; is that maybe why it doesn't work as good as in Python?